# Fiddling with .animate()

Tags: jquery, html

I am playing about with the .animate function in jQuery, I'm fairly new to the function, however for some reason, I can't get it to work. Not sure where I might be going wrong.

First, I define the script in the body tags...

```
<script>
$('.rgt_btn').click(function() {
  $('.ovlBox').animate({
    opacity: 0.0 // I hope this will work? I'm trying to fade this box out, and fade in another... Or something along lines of a carousel.
  }, {
    duration: 2000,
    specialEasing: {
      width: 'linear',
      height: 'easeOutBounce'
    },
    complete: function() {
      $(this).after('// I'm trying to display here another box, but not sure how I can achieve this? The entire <div> box code is quite long to paste here.');
    }
  });
});
</script>
```

Just below it, I have my box...

```
<div id="lmovlb" class="ovlBox"> <!-- Content, lots of it... -->
<div style="display: block;" class="lft_btn"></div>
<div style="display: block;" class="rgt_btn"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Well, first of all, your DOM elements should be present when the script runs. Which means you should wrap that in a function and call it onDOMReady.

Comment: One problem might be that `$(this)` in your complete handler probably isn't referring to what you think it is. What are you trying to target?

Comment: @undefined: thought so too a minute ago, but if you scroll down to the bottom you'll see that it should work that way: http://api.jquery.com/animate/#per-property-easing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PJq9X/1/) that demonstrates (excuse the terrible css). Note that as I said before, you should wrap your code in a function and call it on page load. Additionally, use an external js file, if possible.

Here is an example of how this can be accomplished:

```
var yourFunc = function() {
    $('.rgt_btn').click(function() {
        $('.ovlBox').animate({
            opacity: 0.0
        }, {
            duration: 2000,
            specialEasing: {
                width: 'linear',
                height: 'easeOutBounce'
            },
            complete: function() {
                alert("hello");
            }
        });
    });
}
$(document).ready(yourFunc);
```

Comment: Thank you. How can I wrap the code in a function? I am only using the latest jQuery library atm.

Comment: I have updated my answer to demonstrate how you may accomplish this.

Comment: Fantastic, thank you :) And if I was going to display another box after the one that faded away, how can I fade a new <div> in? Would I have to .animate({ <div> ... </div>}, {settings}); ?

Comment: You do not pass html in the first argument. You pass the css attributes that you want to animate and their destination values. One nice thing you can do is call the function to animate the other div's opacity to 1 in the complete handler.